# How to pass a NUMBER with decimal values as a parameter to a FUNCTION or PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm creating some procedures and functions to make easier the tasks of inserting, deleting or updating rows.
My question could sound silly because sure there's something I'm missing.

**Any time I try to pass a decimal value as a parameter to a procedure or function I get an error.**

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

The next code isn't functional but a way to show the problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1(num1 NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
        BEGIN
        RETURN num1;
        END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    numVar NUMBER;
BEGIN
numVar:= 2.1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Raw Number: '||numVar);

                      /***********Calling test1*************/
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Function Number: '|| test1(2.1));

END;
/
```

Some of the output is in spanish but most of it is in english.

```
Function TEST1 compilado

Raw Number: 2,1


Error que empieza en la línea: 8 del comando :
DECLARE
    numVar NUMBER;
BEGIN
numVar:= 2.1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Raw Number: '||numVar);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Function Number: '|| test1(2.1));

END;
Informe de error -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 6
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

**When I call the function, without decimal parameters, I get no troubles**.

```
          /***********Calling test1*************/
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Function Number: '|| test1(2));
```

Output

```
Function TEST1 compilado

Raw Number: 2,1
Function Number: 2
```

**If I pass a variable instead of a raw decimal number, I don't get any trouble either** and I actually can use a decimal number but it makes less sense for me creating a procedure to insert data that requires defining a variable to pass it as a parameter

```
         /***********Calling test1*************/
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Function Number: '|| test1(numVar));
```

Output

```
Function TEST1 compilado
Raw Number: 2,1
Function Number: 2,1
```

I would like to understand why I can´t pass a raw decimal number as a parameter, maybe I don't understand well the way Oracle casts data before introducing it as a parameter.

Comment: The source of all the outputs is the same code but changing the input of test1(num1 NUMBER)

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your problem. What happens if you replace `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Function Number: '|| test1(2.1));` with `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Function Number: '|| to_char(test1(2.1)));` ?

Comment: This SQL Fiddle shows, that [**your problem cannot be reproduced using just Oracle engine**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/edb03/24).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem seems to be specific to Oracle SQL Developer.

I have **Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 64bit**, and when I tested it in **TOAD 12.0.0.61** everything worked perfectly, but not in **Oracle SQL Developer 17.2.0.188**.

How did I test it:

First, create procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(x$n in NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN  
    RETURN x$n;
END;
```

---

### Testing in TOAD

**Test #1, with `.`**:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';

DECLARE
    numVar$n NUMBER;
BEGIN
    numVar$n:= 2.1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Raw Number: '||numVar$n);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Function Number: '||test_function(2.1));
END;
```

Output:

```
Raw Number: 2.1
Function Number: 2.1
```

**Test #2, with `,`**:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';

DECLARE
    numVar$n NUMBER;
BEGIN
    numVar$n:= 2.1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Raw Number: '||numVar$n);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Function Number: '||test_function(2.1));
END;
```

Output:

```
Raw Number: 2,1
Function Number: 2,1
```

---

### Testing in Oracle SQL Developer

In **Oracle SQL Developer** Test #1 works fine, but Test #2 raises **ORA-06502** - this is your case.

**Solution #1**: use `to_number('2,1')` instead of `2.1`:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';

DECLARE
    numVar$n NUMBER;
BEGIN
    numVar$n:= 2.1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Raw Number: '||numVar$n);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Function Number: '||test_function(to_number('2,1')));
END;
```

Output:

```
Raw Number: 2,1
Function Number: 2,1
```

**Solution #2**: change `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` during execution:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';

DECLARE
    numVar$n NUMBER;
    nnc$c VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    numVar$n:= 2.1;

    SELECT value
    INTO   nnc$c
    FROM   nls_session_parameters
    WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Raw Number: '||numVar$n);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Function Number: '||test_function(2.1));

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='''||nnc$c||'''';
END;
```

Output:

```
Raw Number: 2.1
Function Number: 2.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the problem depends on your `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` parameter.

Try

```
select value
    from nls_session_parameters
    where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';

VALUE                                  
----------------------------------------
,.
```

Check this value. Change parameter like ;

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';
```

Change '.' and ',' order. I changed for session you can change for it system.

In conclusion ;

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';
DECLARE
    numVar NUMBER;
BEGIN
numVar:= 2.1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Raw Number: '||numVar);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Function Number: '|| test1(2.1));
```

Comment: [`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS affects the display of numeric data`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options072.htm#OLADM413).

Answer (score 1):

As your output shows, the decimal separator in your settings is comma (Spanish Culture) not dot. So, you must write `TO_NUMBER('2,1')` instead of `2.1`

Comment: Culture specific [numeric literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i139891)? I am no Oracle expert but are you sure?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. Take a look at the output: `Function Number: 2,1`

Comment: I expect that `test1(2,1)` would raise an error about number of arguments